# Problems with setting pointers correctly while creating singly-linked list

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list, singly-linked-list

```
struct Number_Node
{
    int number;
    struct Number_Node* next_number;
};

int counter=0;

int main()
{
    int input=0;
    Number_Node* n;
    Number_Node* h;
    Number_Node* t;
    do
    {
        cout << "Enter Number: ";
        cin >> input;
        n = new Number_Node;
        n->number=input;
        t=n;
        if(counter==0)
        {
            h=n;
            counter++;
        }
        t->next_number=n;
        t=t->next_number;
        n->next_number=NULL;

    }while(input!=-1);

    Number_Node *tmpPtr;
    tmpPtr=h;
    while(tmpPtr!=NULL)
    {
        cout << tmpPtr->number << endl;
        tmpPtr=tmpPtr->next_number;
    }
    return 0;

}
```

This is my code, for some reason, only the first node prints and then the thing ends. What am I doing wrong here? Also, what is the idea behind sorting a linked list from low to high?

Comment: With linked lists, the best debugging method is to draw it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, what you do is:

```
n = new Number_Node;
t=n;
t->next_number=n;
t=t->next_number;
n->next_number=NULL;
```

which is equal to:

```
n = new Number_Node;
n->next_number=n;
n=n->next_number;
n->next_number=NULL;
```

which means you never set the `next_number` pointer properly. Your code should look like this:

```
Number_Node* newNode  = NULL;
Number_Node* head     = NULL;
Number_Node* lastNode = NULL;
do
{
    // create new node:
    cout << "Enter Number: ";
    cin >> input;
    newNode = new Number_Node;
    newNode->number = input;
    newNode->next_number = NULL;

    // make last node to point to new node:
    if (lastNode)
        lastNode->next_number = newNode;

    // set the head:
    if (counter == 0)
    {
        head = newNode;
        counter++;
    }

    // store the last node:
    lastNode = newNode;

} while (input != -1);
```

Comment: @LihO so newNode is a temporary node which will connect the links, right?

Comment: @MokammelHossainSanju: `newNode` is newly created node. Important here is `lastNode` that is still pointing to last node even after another `newNode` has been created. That allows you to create a link from `lastNode` to `newNode`.

Comment: @LihO also I am kinda confused about what `if (lastNode)` is doing, would you mind explaining?

Comment: @MokammelHossainSanju: When first node is created, there is no such a thing as last node, that's why `lastNode` is equal to `NULL` in that case. `if (lastNode)` makes sure that `lastNode->next_number = newNode;` is called only when `lastNode` truly exists (is not `NULL`).

Comment: @LihO thanx a lot, that explains everything.